# Stanford parser and nltk produce (regular expression matching?) error

Tags: python, parsing, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use Stanford parser with nltk, but this simple code

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser

parser = StanfordParser('stanford-parser.jar','stanford-parser-3.5-models.jar')
```

gives me following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp_parser_new.py", line 4, in <module>
    parser = StanfordParser('stanford-parser.jar','stanford-parser-3.5-models.jar')
  File     "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nltk/parse/stanford.py", line 99, in __init__
key=lambda model_name: re.match(self._MODEL_JAR_PATTERN, model_name)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > _sre.SRE_Match()
```

Can you suggest me solution to this problem? Thank you!

Edit: solved with rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have solved this problem. But it don't know the reason.
In your line `"parser = StanfordParser('stanford-parser.jar','stanford-parser-3.5-models.jar')"` remove the `.jar` part.
And get in your `.jar` file folder.  both remove `.jar`, 
Then run your program.